# Why is JSON.parse changing the values in nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker, angular-cli

To learn Angular 2, I made a [Connect Four game](https://cmermingas.github.io/connect-four-web-worker/) with Angular CLI when it used SystemJS.

I am replicating the effort from scratch with the new Webpack-based CLI and I am having a strange problem...

The following method receives a string with JSON-encoded data and initializes a new game instance with it. I added a few `console.log` to show the problem:

```
export class ConnectFourGameModel {
  static fromJSON(jsonString: any): ConnectFourGameModel {
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    console.log('*** from JSON (compare the "columns" array between jsonString and jsonData below) ***');
    console.log('jsonString: ', jsonString);
    console.log('jsonData: ', jsonData);

    ...
    return result;
}
```

When this runs, the first `console.log` shows the JSON string correctly:

```
jsonString:
{... Several fields here ...
 "columns":[[0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
}
```

But the second `console.log`, which is just the result of calling `JSON.parse` on this string, seemingly randomly changes the values:

```
jsonData:
> Object {... Several fields here ...
  > columns: Array[15]
    V 0: Array[6]
        0: 2     <-- Should be 0
        1: 2     <-- Should be 0
        2: -1    <-- Should be 0
        etc...
```

**Why is this happening?**

You can probably see it better if you [load the app on Github Pages](https://cmermingas.github.io/connect-four-webpack/), open the JavaScript console on the browser, and click on any column to make a move.

The repository is on Github: https://github.com/cmermingas/connect-four-webpack

I looked for questions here regarding *parsing nested arrays with JSON.parse* but I couldn't relate this issue to the ones I found.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're changing the data. Objects shown via `console.log` are *live* so changes made to their properties will be shown, even after being logged

Comment: What @Phil said. If you set a breakpoint at the `console.log` line, you also get to inspect `jsonData`, where you can see that it is indeed a 1:1 decoding of `jsonString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your string example into a fiddle, it appears to parse just fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/z67Lgyrm/

What is likely happening is that you are changing the data after your `console.log()` call. When you click the expand arrow in the log, it is actually showing the value of the object *now*.

Also you seem to be using `slice()` on the columns array, but because it is multidimensional, it is only making a copy of the the references to the child arrays (i.e. not actually copying the values).

See here for a possible solution: [Create copy of multi-dimensional array, not reference - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756482/create-copy-of-multi-dimensional-array-not-reference-javascript)