# Why can't I make a copy of this 2d array in JS? How can I make a copy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy, conways-game-of-life

I'm implementing a John Conway Game of Life, but I'm having a weird problem. Here is a short version if the code giving me trouble:

```
let lifeMap = [
  [true, false, false],
  [false, false, false],
  [false, false, false]
];
let oldLifeMap = lifeMap.slice();
for (let row = 0; row < lifeMap.length; row++) {
  for (let val = 0; val < lifeMap[row].length; val++) {
    let bool = lifeMap[row][val];
    let newBool = false; // here is where I would determine if cell is alive/dead
    lifeMap[row][val] = newBool;
    if (row === 0 && val === 0) console.log("at (0,0)", oldLifeMap[0][0]);
  }
}
```

In response to this code, JavaScript prints `at (0,0) false`. I need it to stay `true` until the next generation starts.

I thought doing `let oldLifeMap = lifeMap.slice()` would fix it, but it doesn't, and I'm not sure why. (Shouldn't it *copy* the 2d array and not create a second ref to it?)

Anyway, what is going on here, and how do I successfully make an actual copy of `lifeMap` here?

Comment: The outer array is a copy, but each inner array remains a reference. That is expected behavior from what you're doing.

Comment: gotcha. How do I make a deep copy then?

Comment: `.map(a => a.slice())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: I'll try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756482/create-copy-of-multi-dimensional-array-not-reference-javascript

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that looks slick. I'll do that first

Comment: Yeah, that's the best approach I think (and what I was going to write). [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yys7yg07/)

Comment: `var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lifeMap))`

Comment: @epascarello that is extremely inefficient and unnecessary, please don't recommend serialization, especially in the case where the structure of the object is well-known.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It works great. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it works.... and if performance does not matter....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A hat-tip to [@Redu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45949356/1541563) which is good for N-dimensional arrays, but in the case of 2D arrays specifically, is unnecessary. In order to deeply clone your particular 2D array, all you need to do is:

```
let oldLifeMap = lifeMap.map(inner => inner.slice())
```

This will create a copy of each inner array using `.slice()` with no arguments, and store it to a copy of the outer array made using `.map()`.

Answer (score 5):

You may clone an ND (deeply nested) array as follows;

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};
```

or if you don't want to modify `Array.prototype` you may simply refactor the above code like;

```
function cloneArray(a){
  return a.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? cloneArray(e) : e);
};
```

Comment: Interesting proposal, but in my opinion is too generic for a 2D array, which does not require a recursive function.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts `Array.prototype` extension above was just illustrative to give an idea about the algorithm. Surely it must be done by `Object.defineProperty()`. And agreed upon this better be implemented as static `Array.clone()`.