# Javascript class property changes in other variables when changed in one variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

So basically I have a class called Board (this is all for a sudoku website + solver) and it has a constructor that assigns into the property `board` as you see below

```js
class Board {
    constructor(board) {
        this.board = board;
    }
    // some other properties
}

function makeBoard(boardlength) {
   // returns a 2d boardLength x boardLength array of zeros
}
```

then I have two instances of this class

```js
var mainBoard = new Board(makeBoard(9));
var generatedBoard = new Board(makeBoard(9));
```

in the `Board` class there is a property `generateBoard()` that generates a random sudoku puzzle into the 9x9 2d array stored in `generatedBoard.board` upon pressing a button on the screen as follow:

```js
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', function() {
    generatedBoard.generateBoard();
    mainBoard.board = generatedBoard.board;
    generatedBoard.updateBoardHTML();
})
```

This is the **only** line where `generatedBoard.board` is stored into `mainBoard.board`

**The main problem is:**
there is an event listener for key presses (specifically digits 1 to 9) so that the user can solve the board themselves and this part is supposed to take the number input from the user, and store it in the `generatedBoard.board` 2d array. But, when this happens, for some reason the number ALSO gets stored into the `mainBoard.board` 2d array and that is the bug I am trying to solve.

Here is the code for the eventListener for the key press but there are some unexplained bits in it:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (keyCodes.includes(event.keyCode)) {

        for (let j = 0; j < generatedBoard.board.length; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < generatedBoard.board[j].length; i++) {

                if (document.getElementById(j + '-' + i).style.background === 'rgb(197, 197, 197)') {

                    const solution = event.keyCode - 48;
                    debugger;
                    generatedBoard.board[j][i] = solution;

                    if (solution === 0) {
                        document.getElementById(j + '-' + i).innerHTML = '';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById(j + '-' + i).innerHTML = solution
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

As you can see the code should only assign the key pressed by the user into `generatedBoard.board` as i wrote `generatedBoard.board[j][i] = solution` but for some reason when this specific line executes, it does the same for `mainBoard.board`

Comment: The line `mainBoard.board = generatedBoard.board;` assigns `mainBoard.board` to a reference to the `generatedBoard.board;` array, meaning that when you change your `generatedBoard.board;` array, it will change for `mainBoard.board` (as they're referring to the same array in memory). You can instead assign `mainBoard.board` to a [(deep) clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756482/create-copy-of-multi-dimensional-array-not-reference-javascript) of your 2d array board

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks it worked, didn't realize that's how that line was interpreted. You can make this an answer so I can mark it if you want.

Comment: Nice, no worries. I marked it as a duplicate as the answers in the other question should answer this one ;)