# Clone a 4D multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

I know this question has been asked before but all of the answers assume the array is a 2D array and only go one level deep.

I have a 4D array and have tried some of the solutions here and did not get the result. Here's my array:

[image: Image of array]

I tried this answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756482/create-copy-of-multi-dimensional-array-not-reference-javascript) but this only goes one level deep. How do I make it work with a 4D array?

```js
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++)
newArray[i] = currentArray[i].slice();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple recursive function that replaces arrays with copies after recursively handling its values:

```js
function deepCopy(value) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.map(deepCopy);
    }
    return value;
}

const data = [[[0]]];
const copy = deepCopy(data);
data[0][0][0] = 123;
console.log(data);
console.log(copy);
```

Actually looking at the bottom answers of that question, there are already (more complicated) deep copy functions present, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13756542/14274597). You can still use mine if you want a very simply only-deep-copies-arrays version of course.