# How can I clone an array with a function without changing the original array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create a copy of an array but switching the position of the most inner arrays. This is the original array:

```
const primera = [
  [["a","b"],["c","d"]],
  [["a","c"],["b","d"]],
  [["a","d"],["c","b"]]
]
```

I want to create another an array like this but without modifying the "primera" array:

```
[
  [["b","a"],["d","c"]],
  [["c","a"],["d","b"]],
  [["d","a"],["b","c"]]
]
```

I have tried this but when I console.log both arrays, the original array is modified.

```
const primera = [
  [["a","b"],["c","d"]],
  [["a","c"],["b","d"]],
  [["a","d"],["c","b"]]
]

const doubleRound = (arr) => {
  const newArr = [...arr]
  for(let i=0; i<newArr.length;i++) {
    for(let j=0; j<newArr[i].length;j++) {
      newArr[i][j] = [newArr[i][j][1],newArr[i][j][0]]
    }
  }
  return newArr
}

const segunda = doubleRound(primera)

console.log(primera)
console.log(segunda)
```

Any idea how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756482/create-copy-of-multi-dimensional-array-not-reference-javascript

Comment: `const segunda = primera.map(pairs => pairs.map(pair => [pair[1], pair[0]]));`

Comment: You are not modifying the `newArr` array, you are modifying the `newArr[i]` arrays (which you didn't clone)

Answer (score 1):

`...` does shallow copy. So multi-level arrays (and objects) are not copied deeply.

Here is a possible solution, building up on yours.

Firstly, start with an empty array. And push an empty array for every `i`. For every `j` index, push into the child array element again.

No need to think worry about indices error this way.

```js
const primera = [
  [["a","b"],["c","d"]],
  [["a","c"],["b","d"]],
  [["a","d"],["c","b"]]
]

const doubleRound = (arr) => {
  const newArr = [];
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    newArr.push([]);
    for(let j=0; j<arr[i].length;j++) {
      newArr[i].push([arr[i][j][1],arr[i][j][0]]);
    }
  }
  return newArr
}

const segunda = doubleRound(primera)

console.log(primera)
console.log(segunda)
```

Comment: Makes sense, it worked perfect, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sure. Please consider upvoting/accepting this answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

[...arr] is just a shallow copy, which means nested array are still passed by reference and if you change one, the clone version also changes.

For a deep copy, you can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)). This will create a clone for nested arrays

```js
const primera = [
  [["a","b"],["c","d"]],
  [["a","c"],["b","d"]],
  [["a","d"],["c","b"]]
]

let secundo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(primera));

  for(let i = 0; i<secundo.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<secundo[i].length; j++){
      [secundo[i][j][0], secundo[i][j][1]] = [secundo[i][j][1], secundo[i][j][0]]
    }
  }

console.log(primera)
console.log(secundo)
```